# android Project add new activity error ?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having trouble adding new activity to my android Project  because of this error 
error MSG:
R cannot be resolved to a variable  testActivity.java
I really want to know what is correct way to add new activity to my project and how to solve this error?

Comment: post your code and testactivity.java registration in manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to add a new activity:

- Right click in your project
- New > Class
- Enter the name of your Activity.
- In `super class` field: android.app.Activity

Also, make sure you clean your project, close Eclipse and launch it again.

Finally, double check that you included your new activity in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your project a few times. Save the code and clean the project and make sure you have **not used** `import andorid.R;`